# ¿Cómo reemplazar un carácter en una cadena de String?

Tags: java

Quisiera saber cómo reemplazar un carácter de una cadena `String` pedida al usuario con su respectivo código (en *Java*).

Ejemplo:

Cadena original:

```
"Diego lava la loza."
```

Cadena reemplazada:

```
"Diego lovo lo lozo."
```

Comment: Java o JavaScript? Has intentado algo? Date una vuelta por http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que te familiarices con el sitio, bienvenido :D

Answer (score 4):

Te presento la documentación de la función **Replace** en la biblia del JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace (está en español)

```js
var cadenaDeTexto = "Diego lava la loza.";
var resultado = cadenaDeTexto.replace(/a/g, 'o'); 
console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: como hago para reemplazar un solo caracter de una frase? sin reemplazar las otras palabras

Comment: Podrías lanzar la pregunta en el sitio, mostrando lo que has intentado, dando a conocer el input y el output que buscas :D

Answer (score 1):

En java Puedes hacer uso del método [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) para los Strings (cadenas)

```
String cadena = "Diego lava la loza.";
System.out.println(cadena.replace("a", "o"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu deseas reemplazar multiples palabras contenidas en tu cadena, por ejemplo de

```
"Diego lava la loza"
```

reemplazas "lava" por "lovo", "la" por "lo" y "loza" por "lozo" para obtener:

```
"Diego lovo lo lozo"
```

Usando Java, puedes realizar esto, un método sería agregar en un array bidimensional de strings las palabras que deseas reemplazar y las que deseas sean reemplazadas

```
String[][] reemplazos = {{"lava", "lovo"}, {"la", "lo"},
                           {"loza", "lozo"}};

    String cadena = "Diego lava la loza";
    for(String[] reemplazar: reemplazos ) {
        cadena = cadena.replace(reemplazar[0], reemplazar[1]);
    }
```

Donde tendrías como cadena resultante:

```
Diego lovo lo lozo
```

---

O bien otro método, usar el método replace() de esta forma:

```
String cadena = "Diego lava la loza";
String cadenaNueva = cadena.replace("lava", "lovo").replace("la", "lo").replace("loza", "lozo"));
```

Donde tendrías como cadena resultante:

```
    Diego lovo lo lozo
```